# GWT Frame issue: chrome browser not opening authentication poup when opening authenticated url in frame element

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT Frame and setting authenticated URL. chrome browser not opening authentication poup  - shows 401 authentication error.

Below code is used.

```
Frame frame = new Frame(authenticatedUrl);
frame.setHeight("550px");
frame.setWidth("99%");*/
frameHolder.add(frame); // frameholder is a horizontal panel
```

But the frame properly opens the authentication popup in ie, firefox

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on your question a bit with some source code relevant to the problem or maybe a demo?

Comment: Can you add the html and/or javascript being generated.

Comment: Have you tried creating the frame with the zero-arg constructor, attaching it to the document and only then call `setUrl`?

Comment: Yes thomas even that did not work